How to get the Pinch or Zoom amount from a MouseWheelEvent in Java
I am trying to code something where I can pan around and zoom a graphic, but I can't figure out how to get zoom quantity. I am working in a swing UI and I have successfully gotten scrolling to work for both sideways and vertical scrolling using a MouseWheelListener in my JFrame, however the mouseWheelListener isn't detecting zooming. I'm looking for either a way to acquire zoom events from a mouseWheelListener or for a library that can give me zoom events.
I've seen a bunch of people use the MouseWheelEvent.isControlDown() method, however when I try that I don't get any updates, even while zooming.
@Override
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        if (e.isControlDown()) {
            System.out.println("zooming");
        }
    }

I am on a mac laptop and I've tried searching for the mouse or key equivalent of zooming to no avail. I've also tried System preferences > Accesibility > Zoom > "Use scroll gesture with modifier keys to zoom" set to on and "Modifier key for scroll gesture" set to control, but this didn't work either.

You're building a Swing UI, yes?

Correct. Apologies, I will clarify that now

Yeah, so I'm afraid you're out of luck here. Swing doesn't necessarily have an analog for the "modern" gestures since that event API was written in a pre-gestural era. JavaFX has a ZoomEvent which I think may serve you well. The solutions you saw with regard to mousewheel + CTRL worked for a brief period of time on Chrome browser only but no longer works on any browser.

Alright, thanks for letting me know.
